# Is the inequality correct?

Tags: inequality

I have an inequality as follows:

\begin{cases}
x>a \\
y-x> b
\end{cases}

Can I make the above inequality more simple as

\begin{cases}
x>a \\
y> a+b
\end{cases}

Comment: No. Draw the two regions: the first is triangular shaped, the second rectangular.

Comment: Thanks, Could you make above inequality more simple?

Comment: We see that $x$ is in both lines... if you put both inequalities in terms of $x$...

Comment: It depends on what you mean my simple. The only possibility I see is to write it more compactly as $y-b>x>a$, but there isn't really much else to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first set of inequalities implies the second one; but the converse need not hold. For example, let $a := 1;$ let $b := 0$; let $x := 3$; let $y := 2$. Then $x > a$ and $y > a+b$. But $y - x < b$.